# Перебор массива объектов с изменением поля объекта

Tags: javascript, массивы, typescript, объекты

Есть два массива

```js
    const idArray = ['1', '2']

    const userArray = [
      {
        name: 'vanya',
        id: '1',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: 'kolya',
        id: '2',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: 'nika',
        id: '3',
        checked: false
      }
    ]
```

Если в массиве idArray есть id, который есть в массиве userArray, то у нужного user-a необходимо поменять checked на true
В итоге должен получиться такой объект:

```js
    const resultUserArray = [
      {
        name: 'vanya',
        id: '1',
        checked: true
      },
      {
        name: 'kolya',
        id: '2',
        checked: true
      },
      {
        name: 'nika',
        id: '3',
        checked: false
      }
    ]
```

Я пробовал сделать это так

```js
const idArray = ['1', '2']

const userArray = [
  {
    name: 'vanya',
    id: '1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'kolya',
    id: '2',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'nika',
    id: '3',
    checked: false
  }
]
idArray.forEach((id) => {
  const resultUserArray = userArray.map((user) => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      return {
        ...user,
        checked: true
      }
    }
    return user
  })
})
   console.log(idArray, userArray )
```

Но у меня получается массив, у которого только в одном объекте поменялось поле checked, а мне необходимо, чтобы оно поменялось в двух объектах. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, так будет проще (если можно менять исходную структуру):

```js
const idArray = ['1', '2'];

const userArray = [
  {
    name: 'vanya',
    id: '1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'kolya',
    id: '2',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'nika',
    id: '3',
    checked: false
  }
];

for (const user of userArray) {
  if(idArray.includes(user.id)) user.checked = true;
}

console.log(userArray);
```

Но если нужна копия, можно так:

```js
const idArray = ['1', '2'];

const userArray = [
  {
    name: 'vanya',
    id: '1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'kolya',
    id: '2',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'nika',
    id: '3',
    checked: false
  }
];

const resultUserArray = userArray.map(
  user => ({...user, checked: idArray.includes(user.id) ? true : user.checked})
);

console.log(resultUserArray);
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Долго с этим мучился